# mocha test vue template but babel can not analyze `computed:{ ...mapGetters()}`

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, mocha.js, vuex, chai

I use macho+chai test vue template, but when template use Vuex like

```
...mapGetters([
```

it have a bug that  `Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):`

```
 computed:{
  > 18 |     ...mapGetters(['website', 'isCustomer'])
       |     ^
    19 |   },
```

i want completed successful